# Convert DataInput to DataInputStream?

Tags: java, hadoop

How can I convert DataInput to DataInputStream in java? 
I need to know the size of the DataInput.

Comment: [`DataInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) is an interface. [`DataInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) is an implementation of that interface. "Converting" a `DataInput` to a `DataInputStream` has nothing to do with finding the size. In fact, streams don't have a size. All you can do is read the data out of the stream until there is nothing left to read.

Comment: well. DataInputStream does have an available method that is not defined in the DataInput interface. So there could be some value to wanting to down cast.

Comment: Thanks, guys. The situation is I wanna use DataInput.readFully() to read all the data into a byte array. But I need set the byteArray size first, otherwise it will pop up NullException.

Comment: For Example:
    public void getData(DataInput in){
        //how can I set up byte array size here? 
        byte[] value = new byte[];
        in.readFully(value);
    }

Comment: About how large is this DataInputStream expected to be?  1k, 10k, 100k, 1M ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a stream, by definition, really has no begining or end and thus no fool proof way of knowing how much is available, you just have to read from the stream in fixed sized chunks.  It almost sounds like you'd be better off with plain old .read() rather than readFully():

```
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(...);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int lastRead = 0;

    do {
        lastRead = dis.read(buf);
        //do something with 'buf' here

    } while (lastRead > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll encounter difficulty when you want know how many bytes to be read. Simplest solution is to cast it to a `ByteArrayInputStream` and use it's available() method to get to know how many bytes are available for reading.

Following example worked for me

```
DataInput in = (...);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = (ByteArrayInputStream) in;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bis.available()];
in.readFully(buffer);
//use buffer as your wish
```

Comment: This will only work if the object you are working with is actually an instance of ByteArrayInputStream.  Otherwise you will get a class cast exception.