# How can I know a DataInput size?

Tags: java

```
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException{
    //How can I set up the byteArray size here?
    //DataInput does not have available() or length() method.
    byte[] videoByteArray = new byte[size];
    in.readFully(videoByteArray);
}
```

How can I know the DataInput size? Before I read all data into a byte array, I need set up the size first.

Comment: you can't know the size. see the following link and don't mind the different title. Please read all the notes too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576908/convert-datainput-to-datainputstream

Comment: I totally agree that DataInput sucks - it's not a stream so why the heck doesn't the interface define a length/size method? arg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataInput is an interface for reading stream data, i.e. when length may be not known upfront. The idea is to read data chunks into byte array in a loop until you hit the end, indicated by EOFException.

Comment: or read() returning -1, depending which method you're calling.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending a portion of data, the simplest approach to know the size is to send it first in the DataOutput stream.  Otherwise you have to assume you want to read all the data until the end of the stream (and you can't send anything else)

Comment: The situation is I wrote a class which should implement from the Writeable interface of Hadoop. In the Writeable interface, they define the method as public void readFields(DataInput in). I have to use it.

Comment: If you are using DataInput, all the fields have a defined or fixed width.  In this case you can read the message to find out how long it is (or you don't need to know)  For readFully, you have to assume you can determine the length by assuming a fixed width or other information in the message.  Otherwise you have to assume youc an read all the data remaining in the stream, you cannot use readFully to do this. (as suggested by mazaneicha)